# ¿Qué es y como se obtiene el "public key file"?

Tags: ionic

Estoy intentando correr mi primera aplicación en Ionic, siguiendo los pasos de la sección de "getting started". Cuando introduzco por teclado la sentencia: `ionic start myApp tabs` me aparece lo siguiente:

```
Familia Baldán@FamiliaBaldan MINGW64 ~
$ ionic start myApp tabs
√ Creating directory .\myApp - done!
√ Downloading and extracting tabs starter - done!

? Would you like to integrate your new app with Cordova to target native iOS any? Would you like to integrate your new app with Cordova to target native iOS 

an
√ Personalizing ionic.config.json and package.json - done!
> ionic integrations enable cordova --quiet
√ Downloading integration cordova - done!
√ Copying integrations files to project - done!
[OK] Added cordova integration!

Installing dependencies may take several minutes.

  *   IONIC  DEVAPP  *

 Speed up development with the Ionic DevApp, our fast, on-device testing mobile app

  -     Test on iOS and Android without Native SDKs
  -     LiveReload for instant style and JS updates

 ️-->    Install DevApp: https://Esta parte la he omitido porque si no no me 
dejaba publicar este post    <--

> npm i
√ Running command - done!
> git init

  *   IONIC  PRO  *

 Supercharge your Ionic development with the Ionic Pro SDK

  -     Track runtime errors in real-time, back to your original TypeScript
  -     Push remote updates and skip the app store queue

Learn more about Ionic Pro: https://ionicframework.com/products

? Install the free Ionic Pro SDK and connect your app? (Y/n) y
? Install the free Ionic Pro SDK and connect your app? No

-----------------------------------

> git add -A
> git commit -m "Initial commit" --no-gpg-sign
[ERROR] An error occurred while running git commit -m "Initial commit" --no-gpg-sign (exit code 128):



        *** Please tell me who you are.

        Run

           git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
           git config --global user.name "Your Name"

        to set your account's default identity.
        Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

        fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'Familia Bald�n@FamiliaBaldan.(none)')
```

Entonces introduzco `ionic login` y me sale lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La parte que no entiendo es la de "Enter the location to your public key to Upload to Ionic"

**¿A qué se refiere esto?
¿Dónde puedo encontrar mi "public key"?**

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu clave pública suele estar en `~/.ssh` en un archivo generalmente llamado `id_dsa.pub` ó `id_rsa.pub`, *"suele estar"* y *"generalmente"* es porque pueden ser configurados tanto donde se guardan como el nombre de archivo.

si no tenes carpeta `~/.ssh` o no ves ningun archivo **.pub** tenes que generar el par de claves publica y privada:

```
$ ssh-keygen
```

el `passphrase` es una medida de seguridad adicional que solicita una clave por teclado cada vez que usas tu clave publica, podes dejarla en blanco.

Recuerda siempre que es el archivo **.pub** el que haces público, el otro debe ser siempre privado (algunas aplicaciones incluso te piden cambiarle los permisos al archivo de claves para que sólo el user que la genero pueda leerlo)